# How to make a HTTP request in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

How to make a HTTP request in Nim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered in the first couple of lines of the [httpclient](https://nim-lang.org/docs/httpclient.html) documentation, along with POST, file POST, SSL,  Proxy, timeouts and redirect handling...

Sync:

```
import std/httpclient

var client = newHttpClient()
echo client.getContent("http://google.com")
```

Async:

```
import std/[asyncdispatch, httpclient]

proc asyncProc(): Future[string] {.async.} =
  var client = newAsyncHttpClient()
  return await client.getContent("http://example.com")

echo waitFor asyncProc()
```

Answer (score 0):

A sample for a `POST` request, using async.

```py
import httpclient
import asyncdispatch

proc main(): Future[void] {.async.} =
  let client = newAsyncHttpClient()
  client.headers = newHttpHeaders({"Content-Type": "application/json"})
  let res = await client.request("https://stackoverflow.com/",
      httpMethod = HttpPost, body = "some data")
  let resBody = await res.body
  echo resBody
```

Comment: That's not the way. This code doesn't compile, as `await` MUST be in an async proc.

Comment: Right! I did not intented to give a compilable program but rather a sample of the right modules and their usage. I see this can be misleading, just corrected.